# delete rows by duplicate indexes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and I need to drop rows based on a counter.

The dataframe looks like:

```
    column1     column2
id      
1   0.974600    0.400304
2   0.499050    0.546998
3   0.245399    0.675422
4   0.109111    0.664372
4   0.715271    0.169065
4   0.274887    0.072359
4   0.331148    0.317341
5   0.404076    0.347777
5   0.717883    0.763131
```

The counter for this example has keys equal to the index values and values equal to the number or rows that need to be dropped for that index.

```
Counter({1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 2, 5: 1})
```

I've tried to drop the rows using a loop and but I'm getting an error.

```
for k,v in count.iteritems():
    del t.ix[k][:v]
```

This is the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-102-33c0a6ba6f58> in <module>()
----> 1 del t.ix[k][:v]
      2 

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.pyc in __delitem__(self, key)
   1788             # there was no match, this call should raise the appropriate
   1789             # exception:
-> 1790             self._data.delete(key)
   1791 
   1792         # delete from the caches

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.pyc in delete(self, item)
   3647         Delete selected item (items if non-unique) in-place.
   3648         """
-> 3649         indexer = self.items.get_loc(item)
   3650 
   3651         is_deleted = np.zeros(self.shape[0], dtype=np.bool_)

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.pyc in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2391             key = _values_from_object(key)
   2392             try:
-> 2393                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2394             except KeyError:
   2395                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\_libs\index.c:5239)()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\_libs\index.c:4792)()

TypeError: 'slice(None, 2, None)' is an invalid key
```

How can I accomplish this tasks to have a final df that looks like:

```
    column1     column2
id      
4   0.274887    0.072359
4   0.331148    0.317341
5   0.717883    0.763131
```

Comment: your slice operation is invalid

Comment: how would you fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `del` on a DataFrame feels odd to me so I would like to avoid it if possible. To get around that I would recommend finding all rows of a given key and keeping the last `rows.shape[0] - v` entries, dropping the rest.

```
df
       col1      col2
1  0.974600  0.400304
2  0.499050  0.546998
3  0.245399  0.675422
4  0.109111  0.664372
4  0.715271  0.169065
4  0.274887  0.072359
4  0.331148  0.317341
5  0.404076  0.347777
5  0.717883  0.763131

df2 = df.copy()
for k, v in c.items():
    rows = df2.loc[df2.index == k]
    df2.drop(k, inplace=True)
    if rows.shape[0] - v > 0:
        retain = rows.iloc[:(rows.shape[0] - v)]
        df2 = df2.append(retain)

df2
       col1      col2
4  0.274887  0.072359
4  0.331148  0.317341
5  0.717883  0.763131
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid looping over the dataframe you can use merge to find the rows to drop:

```
df = df.reset_index()
df['grp_counter'] = df.groupby('id').cumcount()+1

   id   column1   column2  grp_counter
0   1  0.974600  0.400304            1
1   2  0.499050  0.546998            1
2   3  0.245399  0.675422            1
3   4  0.109111  0.664372            1
4   4  0.715271  0.169065            2
5   4  0.274887  0.072359            3
6   4  0.331148  0.317341            4
7   5  0.404076  0.347777            1
8   5  0.717883  0.763131            2

selector = pd.Series({1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 2, 5: 1}).rename('count_select').reset_index()
selector['keep'] = False 
df = df[df.merge(selector, left_on=['id','grp_counter'], right_on=['index','count_select'], how='outer')['keep'].fillna(True)]
df = df.drop('grp_counter', axis=1).set_index('id')

     column1   column2
id                    
4   0.109111  0.664372
4   0.274887  0.072359
4   0.331148  0.317341
5   0.717883  0.763131
```

Comment: I tried your code, but there is a problem with it. It needs to drop 2 rows with index 4 and instead is keeping 3.

Comment: In the counter example you provide there is only one index 4 entry.